# Doesn't this proof of a partition over the set of positive integers ignore 1 & 2?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider $\mathbb{Z}$ as the set of positive integers. We have the following sets defined over $\mathbb{Z}$:

1. $T_0 = \{n \in \mathbb{Z}\ |\ n = 3k\ for\ some\ integer\ k\}$
2. $T_1 = \{n \in \mathbb{Z}\ |\ n = 3k + 1\ for\ some\ integer\ k\}$
3. $T_2 = \{n \in \mathbb{Z}\ |\ n = 3k + 2\ for\ some\ integer\ k\}$

Is the set $\{T_0, T_1, T_2\}$ a partition of $\mathbb{Z}$?
I understand one way to proceed with this proof is to realize that no matter what integer $k$ is, if for some $x \in T_0$ we apply $x \bmod 3$, the result will be $0$ as $3\ |\ 3k$. Likewise for $T_1$ and $T_2$ we can say we will get $1$ and $2$ for any member of those sets respectively after applying $\bmod 3$. As all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ must fall into one of these three sets, then it must be that $\cup_{i = 0}^{2}T_i = \mathbb{Z}$.

However, I don't seem to understand why it is not the case that instead we have $\cup_{i = 0}^{2}T_i = \mathbb{Z} - \{1, 2\}$ as it doesn't seem that you could obtain the positive integers $1$ and $2$ from any of the constructions specified in the sets. This would make $\{T_0, T_1, T_2\}$ not a partition of $\mathbb{Z}$, but I know the proof is somehow true as it is a frequent example of simple proofs for partitions. There is clearly something I'm missing here, but I can't quite see it.

Comment: It *is* a partition of $\Bbb Z$ as soon as you interpret $\Bbb Z$ in the way it is usually interpreted, namely as the set of *all* integers, including $0$ and negatives. -- But even if you interpret $\Bbb Z$ as the set of positive integers only, note that in the definition of the $T_i$, we allow $k$ to be "some integer", so possibly $\le 0$.

Comment: ooooooh I was totally overlooking the fact that all integers are considered, not just the positive ones